# Hi i'm a newbie in c# and i'm trying to write trimleft function by myself

Tags: c#, function, trim

```
public static string TrimLeft(string word)
    {
        int numberOfLetters = 0;
        foreach (var c in word)
        {
            numberOfLetters++;
        }

        int start = 0, end = numberOfLetters - 1;
        string b = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
        {
            if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(word[i]))
           {
                start = i;

                b += word[i];
            }
            
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Trimmed version: {0}", b);
        return word;
    }
```

i'm trying to write trimleft function by myself i couldnt quite figure out how i did the normal trim version but how can i do the trimleft version of it without using any inbuilt string. functions like substring etc.

Comment: What specifically isn't working as expected?  When you step through this code in a debugger, which operation produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(b)`, and `return word`  ????? This need more explaining!

Comment: i'm trying to write the trimleft inbuilt function by myself i did normal trim and tried to modify it but i couldnt find a way to make this work right now this code jsut takes all the spaces and deletes them even in between words whic i do not want i just want to trim the left side of what is given in a parameter for ex: "    abc defg      " i want this string to turn into "abc defg     "

Comment: When you trim you are removing al white spaces.  So use following :  if(!char.IsWhiteSpace(word[i])).  Also change following : b = word.Substring(i)

Comment: Why do you get the count, cast it to a character, convert it to a string and then parse it to an integer? Why not use the integer count directly without converting it 3 times? Additionally, variables start and end are initialized but then never used.

Comment: Stackoverflow has invented an [edit] button, which is below your question in the line "Share Edit  Follow Close (2) Flag" ....  when giving extra info for the question, you are expected to use the [edit] button.

Comment: i cant use any type of string. method since my teacher doesnt want me to so i can not use substring without me writing the substring function too, i will do that too but is there any other way to get around it for now?

Comment: Fi you want help with your homework, you should (ty to ) explain your problem better. you did leave out all the pre-conditions which your teacher gave you ...   (and again, use [edit] to make your question better!)

Comment: When trying to help you I copied the code, and got an error (_"ErrorCS1061'string' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"_)   Why ?

Comment: yeah it gave me the same error i didnt tried it with count code at first so i changed it something more basic this isnt giving me the same error

Comment: And if you are looking for the framework way of doing it https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a shorter version, it was tested and working properly

```
public static string TrimLeft(string word)
{
    string result = "";
    bool trimDone = false;

    foreach (var chr in word)
    {
        if (chr == ' ' && !trimDone) continue;
            result = result + chr;
            trimDone = true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Trimmed version: {0}", result);
    return result;
}
```

test

```
var word = "  abc def !";
word = TrimLeft(word);
```

result

```
abc def !
```

Somebody could suggest a string builder, but as I understand it is out of the scope of the project

also there is another version but I think that it is out of the scope too

```
public static string TrimLeft(string word)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var chr in word)
    {
      if (chr != ' ')
      {
         if ( i > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Trimmed version:{word[i..]}");
                return word[i..];
            }
            else break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Nothing To Trim : {word}");
    return word;
}
```

Comment: This will remove all spaces, not only the leading spaces.

Comment: Did you test this?  With input parameter "     abc   def    " I am getting "a" as result....

Comment: I just tested it  again with your words, it works properly.

Comment: ok, I cannot repeat the problem I had, now it is indeed working... (sorry )

Comment: yeah that works perfectly fine i never would've thought to use bool to make this thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the first non-space character in your input string, then copy the rest to your result string and return it.

The first non-space char can be found with a loop and the copy operation can also be done with a loop, if `IndexOf` or `Substring` are not allowed when solving this problem.  A string builder could be used to efficiently build your result string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
        public static string TrimLeft(string word)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var chr in word)
            {
                if (chr != ' ') break;
                i++;
            }
            i--;
            return word[i..];
        }
```

see: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQ69YC)

Comment: looks good, but you're cheating if using Substring is not allowed.
`word[i..]` uses Substring internally...

Comment: or is substring using `word[i..]` internally?   (chicken/egg)